# Rcpp sugar unique of List

Tags: rcpp

I have a list of Numeric Vector and I need a List of unique elements.  I tried `Rcpp:unique` fonction. It works very well when apply to a `Numeric Vector` but not to `List`.  This is the code and the error I got.

```
List h(List x){
  return Rcpp::unique(x);
}
```

> Error in dyn.load("/tmp/RtmpDdKvcH/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_272635d5289/sourceCpp_10.so") : 
>     unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpDdKvcH/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_272635d5289/sourceCpp_10.so':
>     /tmp/RtmpDdKvcH/sourceCpp-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-1.0.0/sourcecpp_272635d5289/sourceCpp_10.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4Rcpp5sugar9IndexHashILi19EE8get_addrEP7SEXPREC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for being interested to this issue. 
As I notified that, my `List` contains only `NumericVector`. I propose this code that works very well and faster than `unique` function in `R`. However its efficiency decreases when the list is large. Maybe this can help someone. Moreover, someone can also optimise this code.

```
List uniqueList(List& x) {
  int xsize = x.size();

  List xunique(x);
  int s = 1;
  for(int i(1); i<xsize; ++i){
    NumericVector xi = x[i];
    int l = 0;
    for(int j(0); j<s; ++j){
      NumericVector xj = x[j];

      int xisize = xi.size();
      int xjsize = xj.size();
      if(xisize != xjsize){
        ++l;
      }
      else{
        if((sum(xi == xj) == xisize)){
          goto notkeep;
        }
        else{
          ++l;
        }
      }
    }

    if(l == s){
      xunique[s] = xi;
      ++s;
    }

    notkeep: 0;
  }
  return head(xunique, s);
}

/***R
x <- list(1,42, 1, 1:3, 42)
uniqueList(x)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 42

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(uniqueList(x), unique(x))
Unit: microseconds
         expr   min    lq    mean    median  uq    max    neval
 uniqueList(x) 2.382 2.633  3.05103  2.720 2.8995 29.307   100
 unique(x)      2.864 3.110 3.50900  3.254 3.4145 24.039   100
```

But `R` function becomes faster when the `List` is large. I am sure that someone can optimise this code.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are doing wrong, and it is an incomplete / irreproducible question.

But there is a unit test that does just what you do, and we can do it by hand too:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericVector uq(NumericVector x) { return Rcpp::unique(x); }")
R> uq(c(1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 3.3, 27))
[1] 27.0  1.1  3.3  2.2
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Of course, I put the bad code. In my case `x` is a `List`. I updated my post.

Comment: Sugar functions such as `unique()` are focused on vectors.  Lists are more complicated as they can be nested.  There simply is no pre-exisiting `unique()` for `Rcpp::List` so you may have to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the code in R and adapt for `Rcpp`. Because `unique` in `R` can be applying to `list`. In my case it will be simple because, my list contains only `NumericVector`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there isn't a matching Rcpp sugar function, you can call R functions from within C++.  Example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");
Function do_unique = base["unique"];

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List myfunc(List x) {
  return do_unique(x);
}
```

Comment: Yes -- That will work but it will not be as fast because of the function call overhead.  OP stated that his list contains `NumericVector` so it really is just a matter of 'walking' the list and calling  the Rcpp Sugar function.